# How can I calculate compound interest with different interest rates?

Tags: google-sheets

Assume that I have the following different interest rates for different periods. I would like to calculate a compound interest rate based on these rates for lets say 200 periods. How can I do it elegantly instead of multiplying `int_rate1 * int_rate2 * int_rate3 ...`

```
Year    Month   Interest Rate
2014    1       8.04
2014    2       9.14
2014    3       10.06
2014    4       9.11
2014    5       9.20
```

Comment: What is `int_rate1`, `int_rate2` and `int_rate3`?

Comment: int_rate1 is the interest rate in the first row (the third column), int_rate2 is the interest rate in the second row and so on...

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. What kind of calculations are you subjecting those interest rates to? Are you providing all the information needed? What's wrong with multiplying those values if that's what needs to be done?

Comment: What kind of calculations are you subjecting? It is compound interest. Are you providing all the information needed? Yes, maybe in a complicated way. What's wrong with multiplying those values? You don't want to multiply 200 values one by one as question says. Anyway, @AdamL already answered my question. Thank you for the negative comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093502?rd=1) to provide the product of a range of values, eg:

`=PRODUCT(C2:C201)`

And if you wanted the compound interest effective at each month, then in row 2:

`=PRODUCT(C$2:C2)`

and fill down as far as required.