# How to calculate interest rate from start and end amounts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

What is the formula and result for working out the interest rate required for making £38106 into £73036 in 20 years?

(As if you put £38106 into a bank account and left it for 20 years, never taking anything out or putting anything else in.)

Comment: `=RATE(240,0,-38106,73036)` equals `0.27%`

Comment: Can achieve that by using RATE also here have a look at this thread [calculate interest rate](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66254/how-can-i-calculate-compound-interest-with-different-interest-rates) whether this helps.